# Generate random text file in terminal

Tags: macos, bash, unix, random, terminal

I am trying to generate a random text file on my macbook from terminal. What I am trying is that:

```
tr -dc A-Za-z0-9 < /dev/urandom | head -c100 > RandomFile.txt
```

but im getting

***tr: Illegal byte sequence***

What am i doing wrong?

Comment: /dev/urandom delivers hex bytes in the range 00..ff. Start with `hexdump /dev/urandom` and check the manpage for hexdump's format options of it's output.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Set this environment variable and you should be good to go:

```
setenv LC_ALL C
```

[The answer for which I found on this page](http://www.real-world-systems.com/docs/tr.1.html).

And with that environment variable in place, I see a nicely formatted output:

```
tr -dc A-Za-z0-9 < /dev/urandom | head -c100
Kk4kfjR3O0UraMpfTGicGvYCziFClJQUTO3zCXdo05RTxEUigqPXTkjtiGOsTsaNyqNR3rX2dsmPlHkSdqO5qWBTmIFIYezsekWT[~]:;
```

Comment: thanks, the page is useful. it is actually  export LC_ALL=C
instead of                                                        setenv LC_ALL C

Comment: Yep. It depends on whatever shell your Terminal is using.

Answer (score 2):

```
# Print or assign a random alphanumeric string of a given length.
# rndstr len [ var ]
function rndstr {
    if [[ $FUNCNAME == "${FUNCNAME[1]}" ]]; then
        unset -v a
        printf "$@"
    elif [[ $1 != +([[:digit:]]) ]]; then
        return 1
    elif (( ! $1 )); then
        return
    else
        typeset -a a=({a..z} {A..Z} {0..9})
        eval '${2:+"$FUNCNAME" -v} "${2:-printf}" -- %s "${a[RANDOM%'"${#a[@]}"']"{1..'"$1"'}"}"'
    fi
}

rndstr 100
```

This is my library function for this. The advantage is performance and the ability to assign to a variable directly. Might be overkill for you.